# Right SQL query for calculating SUM of elements of same type

Tags: sql

I have a **Distribution** table like below.

```
ItemKey     DayId    Phase  Usage
300029892   20080702    4   2.323
300029892   20080702    5   2.828
300029892   20080702    6   2.275
300029892   20080702    4   2.312
300029892   20080702    5   2.87
300029892   20080702    6   2.35
300029892   20080702    4   2.238
300029892   20080702    5   2.757
300029892   20080702    6   2.298
300029892   20080702    4   2.262
300029892   20080702    5   2.75
300029892   20080702    6   2.382
300029892   20080702    4   2.273
300029892   20080702    5   2.825
300029892   20080702    6   2.2
300029892   20080702    4   2.34
300029892   20080702    5   2.91
300029892   20080702    6   2.328
300029892   20080702    4   2.26
300029892   20080702    5   2.748
300029892   20080702    6   2.617
300029892   20080702    4   2.27
300029892   20080702    5   2.752
300029892   20080702    6   2.36
300029892   20080702    4   2.287
300029892   20080702    5   2.945
300029892   20080702    6   2.313
```

Now I want to get output as

```
ItemKey,  UsageInPhase4,                      UsageInPhase5,  UsageInPhase6
300029892 Sum values in phase 4 over all days Similarly Ph 5  Similarly Ph 6
```

What is right query? This is what I have so far but it is still not exact output what I want.

```
select Itemkey, DayId, PHase, 
SUM(kwh_Del) over (partition by ItemKey) as TotalKwh,
SUM(kwh_Del) over (partition by PhaseKey)
from [dw].[Distribution]  FER
where FER.ItemKey = 300029892
and dayid = 20080702
```

Comment: Same ItemKey and DayId values in the whole table?!?

Comment: Google "pivot query SQL" for a hint.

Comment: Table will have different itemkeys and different DayIds

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: @jarlh My guess is that this is just a snippet of the entire data set.

Comment: Then adjust your sample data, and the expected result!

Comment: Is the numer of phases fixed or variable?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Its always Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pivot query similar to the following should work:

```
SELECT
    ItemKey,
    DayId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Phase = 4 THEN Usage ELSE 0 END) AS [UsageOverPhase4],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Phase = 5 THEN Usage ELSE 0 END) AS [UsageOverPhase5],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Phase = 6 THEN Usage ELSE 0 END) AS [UsageOverPhase6]
FROM [dw].[Distribution]
WHERE ItemKey = 300029892 AND
      DayId = 20080702
GROUP BY ItemKey,
         DayId
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had a variable number of phases, you could have used dynamic query like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = '
    SELECT
    ItemKey,
    DayId ' + STUFF(
    (SELECT ', SUM(CASE WHEN Phase = '+CAST(d.Phase AS VARCHAR(3))+' THEN Usage ELSE 0 END) AS [UsageOverPhase'+CAST(d.Phase AS VARCHAR(3))+']'
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Phase FROM [dw].[Distribution]) d)
    , 1, 0, '') + '
FROM [dw].[Distribution]
GROUP BY ItemKey,
         DayId'
Exec(@SQL)
```

It is just a dynamic modification of @TimBiegeleisen answer.